# Woocommerce - Changing the total text during checkout and add fee

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to do a simple text update to the checkout page.

So for example, the total currently displays:

> $135.65 (includes $10.35 GST)

But since the total weight of the cart is above 25 kgs, I want to add an additional fee of $2.5 and I now want it to display like so:

> $135.65 (includes $10.35 GST and Handling and Packaging ($2.5))

I actually got the code to work before but after the latest Woocommerce update, my code doesn't seem to work anymore.

Here it is:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', function( $translation, $text, $domain ) {
    
    global $handlingfee;
    global $cartweight;
    
        if ($cartweight >= 25 && $cartweight <= 39)
            $handlingfee = 2.50;        
    
        if ($cartweight >= 40 && $cartweight <= 59)
            $handlingfee = 5.00;

        if ($cartweight >= 60 && $cartweight <= 79)
            $handlingfee = 7.50;

        if ($cartweight >= 80 && $cartweight <= 99)
            $handlingfee = 10.00;

        if ($cartweight >= 100 && $cartweight <= 119)
            $handlingfee = 12.50;

        if ($cartweight >= 120 && $cartweight <= 139)
            $handlingfee = 15.00;

        if ($cartweight >= 140 && $cartweight <= 159)
            $handlingfee = 17.50;

        if ($cartweight >= 160 && $cartweight <= 179)
            $handlingfee = 20.00;

        if ($cartweight >= 180 && $cartweight <= 199)
            $handlingfee = 22.50;

        if ($cartweight >= 200 && $cartweight <= 219)
            $handlingfee = 25.00;
        
    if ($cartweight >= 25) {
        $processingfeetext = ' and <b>$' . $handlingfee . '</b> H&P';
                
    }
    
    if ( $domain == 'woocommerce' ) {
        if ( $text == '(includes %s)' ) { $translation = '(includes %s' . $processingfeetext . ')'; }
    }
    return $translation;
    
}, 10, 3 );

add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'change_calculated_total', 10, 2 );


add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'change_calculated_total', 10, 2 );
function change_calculated_total( $total, $cart ) {
    
    global $handlingfee;
    global $cartweight;
    
    if ($handlingfee > 0){
        return $total + $handlingfee;
    }
    else 
    {
        return $total;
    }
    
}
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Something that immediately stands out in your code is the double use of `add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'change_calculated_total', 10, 2 );`

Comment: And to add a fee the `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees` hook seems more appropriate. Only the fee is then shown separately opposite in the text (number) of the total